# Rails 5 html changes not showing even after clearing each cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, caching, devise

I am new to RoR and using rails5 on windows and used `Devise` Gem for authentication. I have to integrate HTML design for admin section. The problem is that whatever changes that i am making in `/app/views/admins/sessions/new.html.erb` file, they are not reflecting in the browser. I always see default login form of devise in which it shows Email and Password field with shared links.

Event by removing entire html from above new.html.erb file, i can still see login form.

I have tried executing below commands to clear cache but still i can not see my new html changes in the browser.

```
rake tmp:cache:clear

rake assets:clean
```

Not sure what else is required to make it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can look in the server log and check - what view is rendered for this action

Comment: in windows, can you please suggest where i should look?

Comment: Never worked on windows. Where do you run `rails server` command? After it starts you can see all logs

Answer (score 0):

Running `rails generate devise:views` will generate all of the views that Devise uses. Editing the generated sessions/new.html.erb file should update the version you are seeing in the browser.

You can also delete any of the other generated files that you don't need to override.

Source:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views